# Reuse expression in SQL sentence

Tags: mysql, simplify

I'm using MySQL and I'm going mad trying to simplify a bit complex SQL sentence.

The query is this:

```
SELECT `provider`.*,`products`.`placement`,`price`.`price`+
   IFNULL((SELECT `price` FROM `price` WHERE `handle`=
     (SELECT `group` FROM `group_provider` WHERE `provider_id`=`provider`.`id`)),'0') AS `price`
FROM `provider` 
LEFT JOIN `products` ON `provider`.`id`=`products`.`web` 
LEFT JOIN `price` ON `price`.`handle`=`provider`.`id` 
WHERE `products`.`type`='$PRODUCT_TYPE'
  AND `price`.`price`+
   IFNULL((SELECT `price` FROM `price` WHERE `handle`=
     (SELECT `group` FROM `group_provider` WHERE `provider_id`=`provider`.`id`)),'0')>0
```

This query is working perfect, but the problem is that I have a repeated item and I don't know how to simplify it. The repeated item I'm talking is:

```
  `price`.`price`+
   IFNULL((SELECT `price` FROM `price` WHERE `handle`=
     (SELECT `group` FROM `group_provider` WHERE `provider_id`=`provider`.`id`)),'0')
```

Any idea to simplify it? Thanks

Comment: A view it's not an option due to database is using MyISAM. As far as I know MyISAM doesn't support views :(

Answer (score 0):

[Create a view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) of your data that includes the extra column and query this view. Once you have created the view the query becomes very simple:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_view
WHERE type = 42
AND price > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The `SELECT` is evaluated after the `WHERE` clause so column aliases defined in the `SELECT` are not available to use in the `WHERE`.

MySQL is unusual in that it allows you to use column aliases in the `having` clause though so you could possibly rework the query to move the predicate from the `where` clause to a `having` clause.

Alternatively you could create a view or derived table with the following definition

```
SELECT `provider`.*          ,
       `products`.`placement`,
       `price`.`price`+ IFNULL(
       (SELECT `price`
       FROM    `price`
       WHERE   `handle`=
               (SELECT `group`
               FROM    `group_provider`
               WHERE   `provider_id`=`provider`.`id`
               )
       )
       ,'0')>0 AS `price`
FROM   `provider`
       LEFT JOIN `products`
       ON     `provider`.`id`=`products`.`web`
       LEFT JOIN `price`
       ON     `price`.`handle`=`provider`.`id`
```

and reference the column aliases in the `WHERE` clause in a `SELECT` from that as per Mark's answer. I'm not sufficiently au fait with the MySQL query optimiser to know if either of these approaches would have performance implications.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work.

First, you should create view

```
    CREATE VIEW `DB`.`view1` AS 
    SELECT `provider`.*, `products`.`placement`, `price`.`price`+ IFNULL((SELECT
    `price` FROM `price` WHERE `handle`= (SELECT `group` FROM `group_provider`
    WHERE `provider_id`=`provider`.`id`)),'0') AS `price`
    FROM `provider`
    LEFT JOIN `products` ON `provider`.`id`=`products`.`web`
    LEFT JOIN `price` ON `price`.`handle`=`provider`.`id`
```

Create query select for that view

```
    SELECT * FROM `view1` WHERE `price` > 0
```

This only work, if you use InnoDB.

Comment: I'm afraid the tables are not InnoDB

Comment: i think u should mention it(MYISAM, i guess) on your question